# Beste Ersatzaussprache für gerundete Vorderzungenvokale beim Deutschlernen?

Tags: pronunciation

Vorausgesetzt, jemand spricht Deutsch als Zweitsprache, kann aber die gerundeten Vorderzungenvokale (noch) nicht zuverlässig aussprechen: was ist dann die beste Ersatzaussprache?

Hinweise:

- Bitte nehmt die Voraussetzung ernst und antwortet nicht einfach, man könne nur mit gerundeten Vorderzungenvokalen Deutsch sprechen.
- Diese Frage geht zurück auf die Frage [Pronunciation of "Ü"](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/33223/pronunciation-of-%C3%9C). Zu meiner Überraschung sind dort die meisten überhaupt nicht auf die Ersatzaussprachen eingegangen, sondern haben lediglich darauf gepocht, wie sehr ein korrektes *ü* unbedingt erforderlich sei. Also frage ich hiermit explizit nach den Ersatzaussprachen, und zwar nicht nur bei *ü,* sondern bei allen Vorderzungenvokalen.

Comment: Ironically [this answer](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/33224/28897) from your link gave the most intelligible advise, but was most downvoted.

Comment: Die Frage is zweideutig. Meinst du "Welche Aussprache soll man einem Schüler empfehlen, der die richtige Aussprache noch nicht beherrscht?" oder "Welche falsche Aussprache stört am wenigsten?"

Comment: Beide Aspekte interessieren mich.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Verschiedene Ersatzaussprachen rangiert nach Präferenz:

1. Ersatz durch die entsprechenden **ungerundeten Vorderzungenvokale** (also /i/ statt /y/ und /e/ statt /ø/). Verschiedene Gründe sprechen dafür, dass dies die beste Ersatzaussprache ist:

   - Die phonetische Ähnlichkeit ist am grössten, sowohl artikulatorisch (für richtige gerundete Vorderzungenvokale braucht es zusätzlich nur noch die Rundung der Lippen) als auch perzeptiv (wer Deutsch vom Hören lernt, gebraucht diese Ersatzaussprache natürlich).
   - In den deutschen Dialekten ist eine Entrundung der Vorderzungenvokale weit verbreitet.
   - In der deutschen Poesie können *ü* und *ö* sich reimen auf *i* und *e,* aber nie auf *u* und *o.* Dies ist ein Relikt aus der Zeit der klassischen deutschen Literatur, als die Entrundung der Vorderzungenvokale in der Standardsprache üblich war.
2. Ersatz durch durch ein **Hinübergleiten** zwischen dem entsprechenden ungerundeten Vorderzungenvokal und dem entsprechenden Hinterzungenvokal (also /iu/ oder /ui/ statt /y/ und /eo/ oder /oe/ statt /ø/).

   - Eine solche Ersatzaussprache kann wohl entstehen, wenn man einer schlechten Anleitung für die Bildung der gerundeten Vorderzungenvokale folgt.
   - Es ist gewissermassen ein Kompromiss aus (1) und (3).
3. Ersatz durch die entsprechenden **Hinterzungenvokale** (also /u/ statt /y/ und /o/ statt /ø/).

   - Wer Deutsch vom Schreiben lernt, verwendet eher diese Aussprache – sie besteht eigentlich darin, dass man die Umlautpünktchen einfach ignoriert.
4. Ausspracheregeln der eigenen **Muttersprache.** Beispiele bei englischer Muttersprache: das *üh* in *Führer* auf dieselbe Art aussprechen wie das *u* in *fury,* das Wort *für* auf dieselbe Art aussprechen wie das englische Wort *fur.*

Answer (score 6):

Ich denke, die Frage geht von einer falschen Voraussetzung aus.

Die Empfehlung einer guten Annäherung an Laute wie ö und ü kann nicht universell (für die gesamte Menschheit) sein. Vielmehr kommt es gänzlich darauf an, welche Erstsprache(n) der Lernende hat und dementsprechend welches phonetische Repertoire im physisch zur Verfügung steht.

Leute mit muttersprachlicher Beherrschung von Turksprachen haben zum Beispiel keinerlei Problem mit ö und ü.<sup>1</sup>

Andere Leute bzw. Sprachen mögen "Ersatzvokale" haben, die nahe genug sind und ihnen empfohlen werden können. Diese kann man aber nur identifizieren, wenn man die Phonetik der Herkunftssprache kennt.

Ein Weg wäre also, den Lernenden einmal alle Vokale, die er aus seiner Herkunftssprache / seinen Herkunftssprachen kennt, ausführen zu lassen, und dann ihm den nächstliegenden zu empfehlen. - Wenn man überhaupt diesen Weg gehen will. Ich finde Pied Piepers Antwort "Die beste Annäherung ist der Versuch" eigentlich treffend.

---

<sup>1</sup> Türkeitürkisch: *Müdürmüsünüz?*- Deutsch: *Sind Sie der Chef?*

Comment: Ich denke, du hast die Frage nicht richtig gelesen. Ich habe doch geschrieben, dass es mir um Leute geht, welche «die gerundeten Vorderzungenvokale (noch) nicht zuverlässig aussprechen» können. Logisch gehören Türkischsprachige nicht dazu.

Answer (score 2):

Der beste Ersatz für die gerundeten Vorderzungenvokale ist das was herauskommt, wenn man **versucht** sie richtig auszusprechen.

Comment: Was für ein phonetisches Merkmal ist ±Versuch?

Comment: Soso. Aber was ist denn die beste _Ersatzaussprache,_ die versucht, sich der richtigen anzunähern?

Comment: @mach Das was der Student **kann**

Comment: Und wenn er, wie explizit vorausgesetzt, kein /y/ oder /ø/ _kann,_ was ist dann der beste Ersatz? …

Comment: @mach Ich finde diese Antwort korrekt. Der beste Ersatz ist tatsächlich das was herauskommt, wenn du versuchst das nachzusprechen was du hörst, etwa bei der Suche nach Audiobeispielen. Du kannst etwa ein Ü als U aussprechen, das wäre wahrscheinlich noch am besten verständlich. Aber besser ist es wenigstens das Ü zu versuchen, das wird sicher noch näher am richtigen Ü sein als ein U. Sich bewusst etwas einfaches falsches anzugewöhnen ist der falsche Weg, davon kommst du schlecht wieder weg.

Comment: Die Frage hängt von so vielen Variablen und individuellen Vorraussetzungen bzw. sprachlicher Herkunft ab, dass dies die beste Antwort ist.

Comment: Das Problem ist, daß das, was der Sprecher als beste Annäherung
betrachtet, und das, was der Hörer als beste Annäherung betrachtet,
nicht unbedingt das gleiche ist.
Standardbeispiel: Ein Russe, der Probleme mit dem deutschen /h/
hat, könnte /h/ durch /g/ ersetzen, durch /x/ ("ch") ersetzen
oder komplett auslassen. Wahrscheinlich empfindet er /g/ als
beste Annäherung. Er wird aber von einem Deutschen bestimmt besser
verstanden, wenn er /h/ durch /x/ ersetzt.